# Print on client default printer instead of server

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, printing

I host my application on a remote webserver and when I click the "Print" button on the client computer I receive the error that "No Printers Installed" from which I understood that the application is trying to look for printers on the server instead of the client computer.

I'm using this code for printing :

```
 protected void BtnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
            pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
            pd.Print();  // Prints on remote server
        }

        private void PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            // QR Code
            QRCodeEncoder encoder = new QRCodeEncoder();
            encoder.QRCodeScale = 3;
            String EmployeeId = this.Request.QueryString.Get("EmployeeId ").ToString();
            Bitmap img = encoder.Encode(EmployeeId );

            Point loc = new Point(1, 1);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, loc);
        }
```

EDIT: 
I've seen similar questions on Stack Over flow that use "Print Dialog" to open the dialog for the user to choose from his computer. I got two problems with that: 
1- The PrintDialog is only available in windows forms applications
2- I would like to preserve the option to to a 1-click print for the qr code, instead of increasing the number of clicks the user has to do.

Comment: You should go with javascript or jquery to achieve this. Writing code at server would not solve your purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code that is writen in C# - Code Behind, is always  running on the server side

If you want to print document on the client machine, you should render the document as html - so it will display in the browser, and then execute javascript function print();
javascriopt code is always runing on client side.
You can use [Data Uri](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs) in order to display the image in the browser, before printing

for example :

```
 protected void BtnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       QRCodeEncoder encoder = new QRCodeEncoder();
        encoder.QRCodeScale = 3;
        String EmployeeId = this.Request.QueryString.Get("EmployeeId ").ToString();
        Bitmap img = encoder.Encode(EmployeeId );

        Response.Write("<img src='data:image/bmp;base64,"+ImageToBase64(img,ImageFormat.Bitmap)+"' width='100' height='100' />"); //render image as html

Response.Write("<script>window.print();</script>"); //print page


    }


public string ImageToBase64(Image image, 
  System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
{
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    // Convert Image to byte[]
    image.Save(ms, format);
     byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

    // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        return base64String;
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using internet explorer and the function "window.print()" causes the Internet Explorer to hang and shuts down all windows. Any idea how to solve that ?

Comment: Do you see the image rendered properly? , if so, remove the Window.print command, and simply click on file->print., if this is working than window.print should work as well in every browser. I believe the problem is in the html it self

Comment: Yes, its rendered properly. I just tried running it in compatibility mode of IE and it seems to work fine.